# Simplest way to honor only the latest of a series of javascript/jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, last-modified, typewatch

I have to imagine that this is a common use case for javascript/jQuery, so forgive me if it's somewhere else on the site, I searched for it and couldn't find this basic use case.

I have a visible div (A).  Hovering that div displays some other divs (B & C).  Unhovering any of those divs (A, B, or C) will hide the two shown divs (B & C).

Simple enough, right?  The problem is that that simple behavior leads to ugliness when you hover and un-hover a number of times in quick succession, since the events all stack and then it just acts like an accordian for a while.

I tried bringing the typewatch function into the equation:

```
var typewatch = (function(){
      var timer = 0;
      return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
      }  
    })();
```

But I wasn't able to use it correctly, I guess (perhaps I would have to call a single custom toggle function that calls typewatch itself, or something?).

For ease of understanding, here is a jsfiddle of the exact case:
http://jsfiddle.net/tchalvakspam/KG3P9/7/

But speaking in general, how can I catch multiple events and only honor the latest one?

Comment: You're not using jQuery's native animation abilities (and more specifically [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)) because....

Comment: This thing isn't coded right anyway...You are accordioning(?) when leaving A...to go to B!

Comment: Whoops, yeah, I realized that moving from a to b was going to cause problems, I should just be triggering on the footer container as a whole.

Comment: @brad as far as using animate and stop as an alternative, I guess I could try that, sure, haven't really used animate much before.

Comment: @josh.trow There we go, updated it to only trigger via hover() of the footer element itself instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually something that used to bother me a lot. Before you animate, call [`$.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) which will freeze any present animation in its tracks, and pick up with the new goal you give it.

```
$("#container")
  .mouseenter(
    function(){
     $(".panels", this).stop(true, true).slideDown(); 
    })
  .mouseleave(
    function(){
     $(".panels", this).stop(true, true).slideUp();
    }
  );
```

This follows the documentation provided in the jQuery API for the [`$.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method itself as they present a similar example, using a single image.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/adeqef/2/edit

Comment: Not perfect when you wave a mouse around over it, but it'll work well enough for my current use case.

Comment: @Tchalvak It's definitely not perfect, but it's nearly there ;)

Comment: Yeah.  Here I thought that I had a simple use case on my hands... :p

Answer (score 2):

I use e.preventDefault() with jQuery events to stop the event from propagating up the tree.